# How to read data from Telnet session

Tags: go, telnet

I'm trying to create a tool to connect to a network device by Telnet and send some commands (Expect-like with certain additional requirements) using [go-telnet](https://godoc.org/github.com/reiver/go-telnet).

To the moment I managed to create a connection and send commands with something like this:

```
func main() {
    var loginBuffer = [6]byte{'r', 'o', 'o', 't', '\r', '\n'}
    var login = loginBuffer[:]

    conn, err := telnet.DialTo("10.10.10.2:23")
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    conn.Write(login)
}
```

Using Wireshark I can see the device responding, however I cannot read any response data. Guess I'm using Read() in a wrong way, not sure.

Would appreciate a working example or an explanation of how to capture and process response data in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks everyone, who spared their time to answer my question. I managed to identify the problem:

1. Every time I created a read buffer it was too big (1024 bytes) so the program was waiting for it to fill up. Now I'm using a cycle reading to a 1 byte buffer.
2. It seems, I also needed some criterion for the function to stop reading and proceed with sending commands.

Here is the working piece of code:

```
// Thin function reads from Telnet session. "expect" is a string I use as signal to stop reading
func ReaderTelnet(conn *telnet.Conn, expect string) (out string) {
    var buffer [1]byte
    recvData := buffer[:]
    var n int
    var err error

    for {
        n, err = conn.Read(recvData)
        fmt.Println("Bytes: ", n, "Data: ", recvData, string(recvData))
        if n <= 0 || err != nil || strings.Contains(out, expect) {
            break
        } else {
            out += string(recvData)
        }
    }
    return out
}

//convert a command to bytes, and send to Telnet connection followed by '\r\n' 
func SenderTelnet(conn *telnet.Conn, command string) {
    var commandBuffer []byte
    for _, char := range command {
        commandBuffer = append(commandBuffer, byte(char))
    }

    var crlfBuffer [2]byte = [2]byte{'\r', '\n'}
    crlf := crlfBuffer[:]

    fmt.Println(commandBuffer)

    conn.Write(commandBuffer)
    conn.Write(crlf)
}

func main() {
    conn, err := telnet.DialTo("10.10.10.2:23")
    if nil != err {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Print(ReaderTelnet(conn, "Login"))
    SenderTelnet(conn, "root")
    fmt.Print(ReaderTelnet(conn, "Password"))
    SenderTelnet(conn, "root")
    fmt.Print(ReaderTelnet(conn, ">"))
}
```

Comment: I think I understand now. Well, Read on sockets returns after reading as many bytes as is available in the socket buffer maintained by the OS. So reading into a slice of length 1024 should have went OK — reading 1 to 1024 bytes. If the connection provided by that Telnet package works differently, it's a bug in it. Now, as far as I understand, your device implements textual protocol. Such protocols are best dealt with by using "line-wise" processing; in your case a line is any number of bytes terminated by CRLF sequence.

Comment: …to deal with that, first wrap your Conn in a `bufio.Reader` and then use it's ReadLine or ReadBytes methods to read complete lines.

Comment: Thank you Alexander for your example. Just a question: I noticed that if (for example) the "Login" string never appears and the input streams ends this statement waits forever:
n, err = conn.Read(recvData)
Did someone noticed this behaviour?
I try to play with time.AfterFunc function without success.

Comment: Hey, Cristian. I suggest checking a different Telnet library: https://github.com/ziutek/telnet It has a  set of examples for expect-like functionality you can fine-tune for your needs. As for terminating the read process, you should  use [select](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/6) with default clause to check for timeout expiration within the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your read operation from connection ? 
I think you need to call conn.read(buffer) to read from the connection and write it to buffer

```
https://godoc.org/github.com/reiver/go-telnet#Conn.Read
```

The examples are not helping much with hte package that you are using. May be the following example taken out of different telnet go package would be more helpful.

```
https://github.com/ziutek/telnet/blob/master/examples/unix-cisco/main.go
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did, however execution "hangs" at  conn.Read() as if expecting to receive something and never receiving. To tell the truth, I cannot even begin to imagine how to deal with it=(

Comment: @Alexander, …so why have you decided to not include this piece of code into your question? You have basically asked about why something does not work without showing what that "something" really is. Please show a complete piece which does not work. Ideally, it would be cool to see what data the device sends (to correlate that with what you do.)

Comment: @kostix sorry about this, since I tried about ten different options and none of them worked, I was unsure of which one to post.